# CometD long polling making session to never time out

Tags: session, timeout, polling, cometd

I am using ExtJs + CometD on ui side and Spring + Jetty as backend for my application. The user gets authenticated using spring authentication manager (j_spring_security_check).
The normal http request goes on a particular url pattern (/myapp) and the cometd communication happens on a different url pattern (/cometd).

I have a session time out value set on the server as 30 mins. Once the user is logged in, the CometD activity starts (like handshake, connect etc.). I am having Bayex transport for cometD to use as WebSocket and long-polling. In case of browsers which does not support WebSocket, the CometD communication happen using long-polling mechanism.

The problem is because of the long-polling from CometD client, the session time out counter on the server always gets reset when the heart beat from CometD long polling arrives. Due to this, the session never times out on the server.

Is there a way to avoid the resetting of session time out value for a session if request comes on a particular URL (in my case the cometD url).

Also, is it possible if i can remove the JSSIONID parameter inside the HTTP header which cometD sends to server. Probably if i can remove the JSESSIONID from http header, then the server will not reset the time out counter for that session.

Thanks,
Brij

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked in the CometD mailing lists, see
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cometd-users/xoTRl3lL9_o

Vote for http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-416, it may be included for CometD 2.6.0.

Comment: The above link provides some information on disconnecting the CometD session in case there is no activity between cometD client and cometD server for a particular time interval. My requirement is to avoid the http session time out timer to get reset because of cometD long polling connect request. So, my http session time out will take the precedence and when it times out, i can disconnect the cometD connection as well. I already have the logic to disconnect cometD connection when http session times out. But the problem is HTTP session does not times out because of cometD polling.

Comment: @brij exactly because CometD continues to long poll, your HTTP session never idles.

Comment: @brij exactly because CometD continues to long poll, your HTTP session never idles. If you have a way to detect CometD idleness (long polling excluded), then you can disconnect the CometD session and then have the HTTP session time out. I don't know of any standard way to avoid that servlet containers reset the HTTP session idle timer every time they receive a request. You should not use the HTTP session in CometD application: if your CometD transport will be WebSocket in the future, you have bound your application to HTTP by using the HTTP session and will be difficult to use WebSocket.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Activity Extension. Please follow the link

http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_extensions_activity